# Non-literal meaning of "See you on the outside"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, implication

There is a song "On The Outside" by No Use For A Name and I wondered what the title means. Basically I'm interested in any non-literal meaning of phrase

> (see you) on the outside.

Maybe any connections with another world? But the song is about breaking up relationship, so it doesn't fit. Can anybody explain it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literary interpretation is off-limits here, so you'll have to be content with a literal explanation.

The phrase "See you on the outside!" often appears in prison-break contexts or in contexts where people are trapped inside a room. It can be paraphrased "Here's to us getting out of this place!" or "I'm getting out of here. We'll meet someday on the other side (of the walls)."

So it could be the emotional or mental situation of the speaker is being perceived figuratively as a kind of imprisonment or confinement.